# where is the validation coming from on this file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have this [link](http://dev.posnation.com/test/test.html) and if you click submit without filling any of the fields you get three validations but i have no js files included so where is this coming from

**Here is the all the HTML**

```
<div class="content">
<div class="page row nobor">
        <div class="three_col wide row">    
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h2>email sign up</h2>                      
                <div class="inner">
                    <form method="post" action="/signup_complete" id="signup_form"> 
                        <p>
                            stuff
                        </p>
                        <p class="row">
                            <label>First Name <span class="req">*</span></label>

                            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"  required="true">
                        </p>
                        <p class="row">
                            <label>Last Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"  required="true">
                        </p>
                        <p class="row">
                            <label>Email <span class="req">*</span></label>

                            <input type="text" message="Please provide your email address." required="true" value="" name="email">

                        </p>                            
                        <p class="row nopad nomarg"><input type="submit" value="submit" class="sub_fbut submit" name="submit"></p>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically I need to add more validation to not allow less then 3 letters but i have no idea where this is coming from and how do i alter...ideas?

Comment: The "required" attribute is generating validation in HTML5 form capable browsers. If you need more validation, I'd suggest javascript or a jquery plugin

Answer (score 2):

This is coming from the HTML5 browser capabilities. Meaning this validation only works on modern browsers that support validation attributes such as "required", check out some examples [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/).

If you want browser compliant validation i suggest [this plug in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). **Just remember** people can disable JS so if you have sensitive data validate it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `required="true"` from your `<input>` tags to get rid of that validation.

Answer (score 1):

> if you click submit without filling any of the fields you get three
>   validations but i have no js files included so where is this coming
>   from

It looks like you are using HTML5 forms code here.

It uses `required="true"` or `required`

HTML5 browsers are interpreting this correctly.

Read more: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#required

---

> Basically I need to add more validation to not allow less then 3
>   letters but i have no idea where this is coming from and how do i
>   alter

If you need some simple validation, you could do something like this

```
$('#first_name').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length < '3'){
        alert('You must enter three characters');   
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ZEjEq/

This is just an example.  You could do something like this on `submit()`.

Also, you should validate content on the server side, too.  Just to be sure!